# Как сделать вертикальный текст в базе данных?

Tags: delphi

Borland Delphi Database Desktop.

Вот так вот:

[image]

Comment: См. ответ ниже и помните: Правильно заданный вопрос содержит половину ответа. То есть учитесь доводить суть своей проблемы до собеседников, учитесь задавать вопросы и вам на них ответят.

Таки образом, уточните какую систему отчетов вы используете: QReport, FastReport или еще что?

Comment: Может быть, как вариант, перенести данные из таблицы (или запроса) базы в Excel?

Answer (score 2):

Вы понимаете разницу между "базой данных" и например "отчетом" или "печатной формой"?

База данных занимается хранением данных, поэтому с ней такое проделать нельзя. 
Все форматирование текста, шрифты, макеты табличек относятся уже к построению отчета. Для этого вам помимо BDE нужна какая-либо система построения отчетов (FastReport, CrystalReport, или хотя бы файл RTF/DOC).

Comment: в общем вот такую чушь надо сделать в бд 
http://pics.kz/i3/b5/3e/b53e85482fea6dbf02ec7c84d1937d6f.jpg

Comment: Для этого вам надо отдельно спроектировать базу данных и отдельно разработать печатную форму (в вашем случае crosstab/pivot table/сводную таблицу).

Answer (score 0):

Можно делать через excel.apllication.
У Вас база формирована? 
Данные каким образом вбивается?
Если по точнее, то могу помоч.

Comment: делаем через DBGrid и в access

Comment: мне надо сделать вертикальный текст в DBGrid. и еще надо многоуровневый или многострочный заголовок в DBGrid что то такое(срочно)